# Evaluating $\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Is the approach made to this question good enough to be used? My professor multiplies with $e^x/e^x$ instead of making this approach

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$

Solution:
$$\frac{e^x\left(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x}\right)}{e^x\left(1-e^{-x}/e^x\right)} \tag1$$
$$
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1+\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x}}{1-\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x}}=\frac{1+e^{-2 x}}{1-e^{-2 x}} \tag2\\[4pt]
&\Rightarrow \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+e^{-2 x}}{1-e^{-2 x}} \tag3\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1+\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-2 x}}{1-\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-2 x}} \tag4\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1+0}{1-0}=1 \tag5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, this seems fine.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... There appears to be a typo in the denominator of line $(1)$, but it's resolved in $(2)$. The argument is sound.

Comment: While the argument itself works, you've written it in an incorrect way with all those $\Rightarrow$ between every expression. You should use $=$ when things are equal

Comment: I think it is useful to note that
$$\coth x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$